# How can I assign a new ref to every iteration inside a map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, ref

I'm not sure how to ask this question, because I'm still unable to accurately frame the problem.

I've created a useHover function. Below, you'll see that I am mapping over data and rendering a bunch of photos. However, the useHover only works on the first iteration.

I suspect that it's because of my ref. How does this work? Should I creating a new ref inside of each iteration -- or is that erroneous thinking..?

How can I do this?

Here's my useHover function.

```
const useHover = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);

  const enter = () => setHovered(true);
  const leave = () => setHovered(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.addEventListener("mouseenter", enter);
    ref.current.addEventListener("mouseleave", leave);

    return () => {
      ref.current.removeEventListener("mouseenter", enter);
      ref.current.removeEventListener("mouseleave", leave);
    };
  }, [ref]);

  return [ref, hovered];
};
```

And here's my map function. As you can see I've assigned the ref to the image.

The problem: Only one of the images works when hovered.

```
const [ref, hovered] = useHover();

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Styles className="row">
        <Div className="col-xs-4">
          {data.map(item => (
            <div className="row imageSpace">
              {hovered && <h1>{item.fields.name}</h1>}
              <img
                ref={ref}
                className="image"
                key={item.sys.id}
                alt="fall"
                src={item.fields.image.file.url}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </Div>
```

Comment: It seems like it would. Not sure how to implement this though.

Comment: You just need to use `useHover` in the iterator within separate component. @T.J. Crowder answer would solve your problem

Comment: @Dupocas - And agreed, this is a duplicate of that. Sadly that has no upvoted or accepted answers...yet. :-)

Comment: Seems a little selfish to point to my own answer right? hahaha And yours seems way more specific. I'm deleting the comment and upvoting yours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd handle this by using CSS if at all possible, rather than handling hovering in my JavaScript code.

If doing it in JavaScript code, I'd handle this by creating a component for the things that are hovered:

```
function MyImage({src, header}) {
    const [ref, hovered] = useHover();
    return (
        <div className="row imageSpace">
          {hovered && <h1>{header}</h1>}
          <img
            ref={ref}
            className="image"
            alt="fall"
            src={src}
          />
        </div>
    );
}
```

and then use that component:

```
return (
  <Wrapper>
    <Styles className="row">
      <Div className="col-xs-4">
        {data.map(item =>
          <MyImage
            key={item.sys.id}
            src={item.fields.image.file.url}
            header={item.fields.name}
          />
        )}
      </Div>
```

(Obviously, make more of the props configurable if you like.)

Comment: This is great. Feels close. But the image component doesn't have access to item, and I'm receiving the error "'item' is not defined".

Comment: @WesleyBonneville - I just missed out a prop it needs, somehow I didn't see it in the `h1`...

Comment: @WesleyBonneville - I've fixed it.

Comment: Nailed it! I really like this solution. Thanks a lot, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule when you have a parent item with `Array.map()`, and functionality for each array item, refactor the items to a separate component (`ImageRow` in my code).

In this case you don't need to use refs for event handling, since React can handle that for you. Instead of return a ref from `useHover`, return an object with event handlers, and spread it on the component.

```js
const { useState, useMemo } = React;

const useHover = () => {
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
  
  const eventHandlers = useMemo(() => ({
    onMouseEnter: () => setHovered(true),
    onMouseLeave: () => setHovered(false)
  }), [setHovered]);
  
  return [hovered, eventHandlers];
};

const ImageRow = ({ name, url }) => {
  const [hovered, eventHandlers] = useHover();

  return (
    <div className="row imageSpace">
      {hovered && <h1>{name}</h1>}
      <img
        className="image"
        alt="fall"
        src={url}
        {...eventHandlers}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const images = [{ id: 1, name: 'random1', url: 'https://picsum.photos/200?1' }, { id: 2, name: 'random2', url: 'https://picsum.photos/200?2' }, { id: 3, name: 'random3', url: 'https://picsum.photos/200?3' }];

const Wrapper = ({ images }) => (
  <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
  {images.map(({ id, ...props }) => <ImageRow key={id} {...props} />)}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Wrapper images={images} />,
  root
);
```

```css
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```